# Reading large files and filter using contains() java

Tags: java, regex, memory, optimization, filereader

I am reading large log files using BufferedReader in java.I have to filter the contents of the file and store the data in database.
example.

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.log"));
String line;
while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
   if(line.contains("filter1") || line.contains("filter2") ||
       line.contains("filter3") || line.contains("filter4")...){
        //creating object and storing using hibernate
    }
}
```

I have more than 50 such filters and the problem occurs in reading files over 100 MB. A lot of time is wasted in matching these filter strings.

I cannot use Collection.contains(line) as the filters in if conditions are substrings of the line read. The time taken is not due to IO but the filtering of contents and creating objects for storing.

Edit 1 :- filter1, filter2 are just for simplicity only. In actual cases, the filter would be like - "new file", "report","removed from folder","schema","move","copy","added to queue","unique id" etc. These are the specific keyword that I check to see if the line contains relevant data for storing.

Please suggest a better way for achieving the same.

Comment: Try using `containsAny` method from `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsAny-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-

Comment: As presented, there is not much you can do to improve it. If you need to check if a line contains one of 50 strings, you'll potentially have to look for all 50 from beginning to end. If you have more knowledge on the potential position of the string, or that if string A doesn't appear then it's certain that string B doesn't etc., you may be able to improve this a bit. Or you can use a specialized method for searching with a trie so that you don't have to scan through the entire line each string.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8, you can use Files.lines to read file as Stream.

This example shows you how to use Stream to filter content, convert the entire content to upper case and return it as a List.

```
c://lines.txt – A simple text file for testing
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class TestReadFile {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String fileName = "c://lines.txt";
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {

            //1. filter line 3
            //2. convert all content to upper case
            //3. convert it into a List
            list = stream
                    .filter(line -> !line.startsWith("line3"))
                    .map(String::toUpperCase)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        list.forEach(System.out::println);

    }

}
```

Comment: Files.lines in Java 8 will read all lines from a file as Stream of String, which is populated lazily as the stream is consumed. So, if you have a huge file and you only read first 100 lines then rest of the lines will not be loaded into memory, which results in better performance.

Comment: You can use different methods from java.util.stream.Streams class to process lines read from a file before printing them or returning them to the caller. It's not just lambda expression, which is introduced in Java 8, there are many more goodies like this which are hidden behind the aura of big features like lambdas and streams.

Comment: The issue here is not reading the lines. In the original program, the lines are read one by one, not pre-loaded. So you get the same general performance of reading. The OP specifically says that the problem is in the comparisons (filters). Yours is not more efficient. It is not even doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your filters look like. If it really were `filter1`, `filter2`, etc. then you could use a regex like

```
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("filter[0-9]");

... // in a loop
if (pattern.matcher(line).matches()) {...}
```

(you could also avoid the allocation). You don't need an exact filter here, just something excluding non-matching lines with high probability (and excluding no matching line).

For example, you can use 4-grams or alike, use a [rolling hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) like

```
/// Initialization
Set<Integer> hashesOf4grams = new HashSet<>();
for (String s : filters) {
    if (s.length() < 4) {
        ... do some handling for short strings, omitted here as probably not needed.
    }
    int hash = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        hash = (hash << 8) + s.charAt(i);
    }
    hashesOf4grams.add(hash);
}


/// Loop.
for (String line : lines) {
    boolean maybeMatching = false;
    int hash = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length() && !maybeMatching; ++i) {
       hash = (hash << 8) + line.charAt(i);
       maybeMatching = hashesOf4grams.contains(hash);
    }
    if (!maybeMatching) {
        continue;
    }

    // Slow test.
    boolean surelyMatching = false;
    for (String s : filters) {
        if (line.contains(s)) {
            surelyMatching = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (surelyMatching) {...}
}
```

The shifting above ensures that only the 4 last characters matter. Instead of `Set.contains` (with boxing), you could use some primitive collection.

You could use [tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)...

You could also use common substrings. Your example is still too short for anything useful, but something like

```
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("new file|re(port|moved from folder)");
```

could work better than testing everything separately. I guess, tries should be best, but the N-grams are simpler and can work well enough.

In my above implementation, I'm assuming that all filters are of length at least 4.

---

Comment: filter1,filter2 were just for simplicity.

Comment: @AnuragUpadhyaya Please add more strings.

Comment: I have updated the edit ..but there is no fixed pattern in the filters,if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: @AnuragUpadhyaya I see. Look into tries or try to understand the hashing I wrote about. I guess, both should work well. Choose one and I'll explain what's unclear.